# por que obtengo el error "Uncaught ReferenceError: slider1 is not defined at onload"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

no logro entender por que obtengo el error que menciono en el titulo "index.php:111 Uncaught ReferenceError: slider1 is not defined
    at onload"
si alguno muy amable me pudiera colaborar,

```
function uhrzeit(anzeige) {
            Heute = new Date();
            Stunde  = Heute.getHours();
            Minute  = Heute.getMinutes();
            Sekunde = Heute.getSeconds();
            document.getElementById("uhr").innerHTML=Stunde+":"+((Minute<=9)?"0"+Minute:Minute)+":"+((Sekunde<=9)?"0"+Sekunde:Sekunde)+" Uhr";
        }
        function bild1(){
            document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild1.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
        }
        function bild2(){
            document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild2.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')"
        }
        function bild3(){
            document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild3.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')"
        }
        function bild4(){
            document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild4.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
            document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')"
        }
        position=1;
        setTimeout(function slider1(){
            if(position == 1){
                position = 2;
                document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild1.png')";
                document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
                document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                window.setTimeout(slider1, 5000);
            }
            else{
                if(position == 2){
                    position = 3;
                    document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild2.png')";
                    document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
                    document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                    document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                    document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')"
                    window.setTimeout(slider1, 5000);
                }
                else{
                    if(position == 3){
                        position = 4;
                        document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild3.png')";
                        document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
                        document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                        document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                        document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')"
                        window.setTimeout(slider1, 5000);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(position == 4){
                            position = 1;
                            document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild4.png')";
                            document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
                            document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                            document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                            document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')"
                            window.setTimeout(slider1, 5000);
                        }
                    }                       
                }
            }
        },5000);
```

```html
<body Onload="uhrzeit('jetzt'); setInterval('uhrzeit()', 1000); bild1(); slider1()">
```

Comment: En donde declaras `eit()`?  tampoco veo la declaración de `bild1()`. Por favor pone todo el código para que podamos ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: Fran Islas hola, edite el post con todo el codigo

Comment: por favor, corrige la tabulacion del codigo. Da la sensacion de que la funcion `uhrzeit` contiene `slider1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la funcion `slider1` como tal no esta definida. Esta dentro del ambito del settimeout, por lo que no puedes acceder a ella desde fuera. Creo que lo correcto seria que la definieras fuera:

```
function slider1(){
    if(position == 1){
        position = 2;
        document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild1.png')";
        document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
        document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
        document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
        document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
        window.setTimeout(slider1, 5000);
    } else {
                    if(position == 2){
                        position = 3;
                        document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild2.png')";
                        document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
                        document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                        document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                        document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')"
                        window.setTimeout(slider1, 5000);
                    }
                    else{
                        if(position == 3){
                            position = 4;
                            document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild3.png')";
                            document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
                            document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                            document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                            document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')"
                            window.setTimeout(slider1, 5000);
                        }
                        else{
                            if(position == 4){
                                position = 1;
                                document.getElementById("bild").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/bild4.png')";
                                document.getElementById("bild4").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkton.png')";
                                document.getElementById("bild2").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                                document.getElementById("bild3").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')";
                            document.getElementById("bild1").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/slider/punkt.png')"
                    window.setTimeout(slider1, 5000);
                }
            }                       
        }
    }
}

position = 1;
setTimeout(slider1, 50000);
```

De esta manera, ahora slider1 esta definida, y cuando llames al load de tu elemento (siempre que hayas puesto este javascript antes en el head)

Por otra parte, esa funcion slider1 se puede optimizar bastante. Te sugiero que la revises y pongas un switch en lugar de if anidados, adenas que siempre haces lo mismo en cada if, solo que cambiando valores, asi que podrias jugar con un objeto con claves bild, bild1, bild2, bild3, bild4 y valores punkton, bulk... para ir asignando tus blackgroundImages. Eso te lo dejo a ti :)

Answer (score 3):

Javascript, una vez más, tiene peculiaridades interesantes. En este caso te has topado con una de ellas: funciones *inline* con nombre.

El nombre en este escenario sólo sirve para llamadas recursivas, fuera de ese contexto la función se considera anónima.

Tu función `slider1` no es visible con ese nombre fuera del `setTimeout` donde está definida.

```js
setTimeout(function nombreFuncion (n) {
  if (n==0) {
    console.log('Fin');
  } else {
    console.log(n);
    nombreFuncion(n-1);
  }
},0,5);


nombreFuncion(5);
```

La solución es declararla fuera para poder reutilizarla.