# Error en variable no esta definida

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario y cuando ejecuto el evento `onclick` da error, dice que la variable no esta definida.

Este es el botón:

```js
document.getElementById("btnSend").addEventListener("click", function myFunction() {
    var first_name=document.getElementById("first_name").value.toUpperCase();
    var last_name=document.getElementById("last_name").value.toUpperCase();
    var cedula=document.getElementById("cedula").value.toUpperCase();
    var ve=document.getElementById("ve").value;
    var codigo=document.getElementById("codigo").value;
    var phone=document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var email=document.getElementById("email").value.toLowerCase();
    var descripcion=document.getElementById("descripcion").value.toUpperCase();
    
    if(first_name == null || first_name.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(first_name)){
        swal("ERROR:", "El campo Nombre no debe ir vacío!");
        return false;
    }

    if(cedula == null || cedula.length == 0 || isNaN(cedula)){
        swal("ERROR:", "Debes ingresar su número de cedula");
        return false;
    }

    if(codigo == null || codigo.length == 0 || isNaN(codigo)){
        swal("ERROR:", "Debes ingresar el codigo del telefono");
        return false;
    }

    if(phone == null || phone.length == 0 || isNaN(phone)){
        swal("ERROR:", "Debes ingresar su número de telefono");
        return false;
    }

    if(descripcion == null || descripcion.length == 0 || /^\s+$/.test(descripcion)){
      swal("ERROR:", "Debes ingresar un Asunto");
      return false;
    }
    
    
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      "client_data": {
        "id_doc": ""+ve+""+cedula+"",
        "first_name": ""+first_name+"",
        "last_name": ""+last_name+"",
        "email": ""+email+"",
        "phone": ""+codigo+""+phone+"",
      },
      "title": "PROSPECTO DE ALIADO",
      "type": "REQUEST",
      "weight": 1,
      "channel": "WEB",
      "description_markdown": ""+descripcion+"",
      "time_estimate": 2400,
      "business_id": "3606bce0-0d0c-11e8-bf0a-6b5a224d7afd"
    });
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    
        swal({
          title: "¿Estás seguro?",
          text: "Deseas enviar la solicitud ?",
          icon: "warning",
          buttons: true,
          dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {

          if (willDelete) {
            swal("Solicitud enviada!", {
              icon: "success",
              text:" Su número de Ticket es : " +myObj.number,
              title: "Enviado Exitosamente!",
            });
          } 
        });

      }

    });
    
    xhr.open("POST", "https://api.paguetodo.com/issue/issue?user_id=3606bce0-0d0c-11e8-bf0a-6b5a224d7afd");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(data);
    $(":text").each(function(){ 
            $($(this)).val('');
    }); 
});
```

```html
<i>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Enviar" id="btnSend" onclick="myFunction();limpiarFormulario()"> </input></i>

<i>
```

Comment: cual es la variable que te dice que no esta definida? Deberías poner el mensaje.

Comment: Además pon todo el formulario, por favor,, ya que si no, no podemos indicar correctamente el que esta mal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema que tienes , es donde esta ubicada  la funcion `myFunction`. colocare un ejemplo a continuacion:

```js
function myListener(){
  function myFunction(){
      return "chispas";
    }
    return myFunction;
  }

console.log(myListener())
console.log(myListener()())

console.log(myFunction())
```

en el siguiente ejemplo **`myListener`** esta devolviendo una funcion dentro de una funcion esto se conoce como [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), es similar a lo que te esta pasando, la funcion `myFunction` esta dentro del AddEventListener, un caso muy comun de cuando lo usas y no te das cuenta es en el `$().ready({.....})` de JQuery

Para tu Ejemplo lo puedes hacer de dos formas.

1. Quitar el onclick, puesto que ya tienes el addEventListener y es lo mismo
2. Eliminar el AddEventListener y definir tu funcion en tu archivo JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

En el HTML tienes un atributo `onclick` que hace referencia a una función que no existe en ese contexto (`myFunction`). Es un problema similar al de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205668/por-que-obtengo-el-error-uncaught-referenceerror-slider1-is-not-defined-at-onl)

Answer (score 0):

la función `addEventListener` se define así

> document.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture)

lo que espera recibir esta función como segundo parámetro es una *función* no **una definición de una función**:

```
// Definicion de una funcion
function myFunction() {
    ...
}

// Uso de la funcion
document.addEventListener('click', myFunction);

// Lo que creo que querías hacer
document.addEventListener('click', function(){
    ...
});
```

ahora lo que tu tienes es una definición de una funcion dentro del parámetro que recibe `addEventListener`

```
document.getElementById("btnSend").addEventListener("click", function myFunction() {
    ...
});
```

Espero se note la diferencia de como hacerlo bien y como hacerlo mal

Comment: lamento darte -1 , pero el ejemplo que muestras el definir una funcion y agregarla en el listener es valida, de hecho es mas comun de lo que parece es una forma de evitar el callback hell, en los dos ejemplos que mostrastes son realmente validos y de hecho asi lo tiene el usuario; el error que le da es que en el onclick no ve la funcion